# Крякозябры в ответе

Tags: jquery, json, php, javascript

Приветствую Всех!

Использую вот такую конструкцию:

```
$.getJSON("http://test2.ru/adminbook/getBook.php?time=" + Math.round(new Date().getTime()) + "&callback=?", function (data) {
    //alert(data.length);
    alert(data[0].title);
});
```

Данные приходят в виде иероглифов (буквы сверху с тильдами всякими). Все файлы в utf-8, бд в utf-8, header прописаны utf-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А вы попробуйте психонуть и в **.htaccess** дописать строку:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Плюс к этому после подключения к базе сделать такой запрос:

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES "utf8"');
```

Comment: .htaccess - тут не подойдёт.
да и в конфигах апача стоит UTF-8.

добавил после подключения:
$r = $db->query('SET NAMES "utf8"');
$r->execute();

теперь новые крякозябры

Comment: @Deonis, а зачем `utf8` в отдельных кавычках?

Comment: @Construct, кавычки, в общем-то, не обязательны. Просто привычка передаваемые параметры брать в кавычки.

@V_Tjuryakin, тогда способ, который я не очень люблю, но как вариант - перекодировать с помощью **iconv()**

P.S. Кстати, помнится была когда-то аналогичная проблема. В файл-обработчик повесил 

    header("Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251");

Если память не изменяет, то помогло